ElasticSearch and existing data in Mysql
Situation: there is a big database of store's orders.
There is a page on the site with a list of orders and a filter by ID, status and other fields. Now there is a request to the database by sql-request for filtering data.
I want to transfer the search by order status to Elastic Search as a first step.
When changing statuses in dashboard, I have a synchronization to ES. And when on the page with orders list the user filters orders by status, I get information from ES.
But what to do with old orders? There are a lot of them.
The solution that I see:

Write a sync-script that will send all orders and their status to Elastic Search  (long solution)

Do not send old orders to Elastic Search, but filter them on the site side with Mysql-database (not nice solution)


I have no experience with such cases.
Maybe there are best practices?

How many orders are you talking about ... ES can deal with millions of documents

@Paulo Hello! Yes, I understand that. I have a question about how best to synchronize entities with from database Mysql to Elastic.
I think that I should write a script for sending orders and statuses to elastic.

I think you could look at Logstash it is bake to get data from SQL database and send it to elasticsearch via the jdbc input https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html
